# How can I add a line break within Visualforce table cell? (Salesforce CPQ Quote Template)

Tags: visualforce

I need to invoke a line break within a table cell in my Visualforce page code. Keep in mind this is Visualforce infused template content on a Salesforce CPQ quote template. I've tried 
 but it isn't working. Below qlHostIds is a List of Strings. For example, this List might have 3 values (HOST-00798, HOST-00800,
HOST-00799).

```
<table-cell display-align="center" padding="4" border-left-style="solid">
    <block text-align="center">
        <apex:repeat var="hostId" value="{!qlHostIds}">
            <apex:outputText value="{!hostId}"></apex:outputText> 
            <apex:outputText value="&#xA;"></apex:outputText>
        </apex:repeat>
    </block>
</table-cell>
```

This outputs everything on the same line like so:
HOST-00798 HOST-00800
HOST-00799

Inserting < br / > in place of &#xA causes the page to fail rendering.
Inserting < br / > on its own line causes the page to fail rendering.

How can I invoke line breaks after each list value like so:
HOST-00798
HOST-00800
HOST-00799

Thanks.
I've also tried:  &lt and &gt surrounding the br in conjunction with escape="false".

Comment: Are you trying to use HTML? Because this doesn't look like HTML; if you're using a specific framework, you should specify that as well (e.g. React, Bootstrap, Angular, etc).

Comment: I'm using Visualforce in conjunction with Salesforce CPQ template content (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_template_content.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by surrounding the outputText by block tags:

```
<table-cell display-align="center" padding="4" border-left-style="solid">
    <block text-align="center">
        <apex:repeat var="hostId" value="{!qlHostIds}">
            <block>
                <apex:outputText value="{!hostId}"></apex:outputText>
            </block>
        </apex:repeat>
    </block>
</table-cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the line break HTML of `<br/>` inside the `apex:repeat`.

Comment: Tried that. It causes the page to fail rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the escape inside apex:outputText causes it to translate to `&amp;#xA;`, which would cause a problem. Instead, it appears you should simply be able to do this:

```
<apex:repeat var="hostId" value="{!qlHostIds}">
    <apex:outputText value="{!hostId}" /><br />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but get the following error when previewing the document:
An error occurred rendering the document. Please check the Quote Template for invalid HTML markup.